# Validation when having 2 webform in same page?

Tags: blocks, panels, webforms

On Drupal 6, I have 2 different webforms which I have available as 'blocks'. Then I create a 'page panel' and added the 2 blocks. Everything works just fine but I have 2 problems.

1. One comes when sending any of the forms and the validation shows up. Both 'name' inputs are red marked.
2. When the form is correctly sent I'm redirected to the succes page but when I hit the 'back' button it takes me to the webform node instead of the 'page panel'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try changing the field name of one of the 'name' fields to that they are unique across both forms.
2. You'll need to copy the webform-submissions.tpl.php from the Webform module into your theme, and update the link at the bottom.